# Invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'

Tags: c++

This doesn't work. Can anyone tell why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int mean( int );

int main() {

    int array[] = {43, 5, 3, 5, 2};

    cout << mean(array);

}

int mean( int list[] ) {
    return list[0];
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
Invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'
Initializing argument 1 of 'int mean(int)'
```

Comment: In answer to your next question: there is no way to determine the length of the array from the parameter `list` passed to `mean`. You will have to pass it as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are forward declaring the `mean` function using a different signature. Fix your forward declaration:

```
int mean( int[] );
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the brakets in your prototype. Try this:

```
int mean(int[]);
```